# What will be the function to check if the digit of second number can be rearranged to form the first number

Tags: java, data-structures

What will be the function to check if the digit of second number can be rearranged to form the first number, where the number can be between `10 and 1 billion`.

```
x = 544
y = 454
```

Output: **true** (Y can be rearranged to form X)

```
x = 11235
y = 23465
```

Output: **false** (Y cannot be rearranged to form X)

Comment: convert it to a string, sort the string (split into characters, sort the resulting list), compare the two lists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried so we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to checking for **Anagrams** (a word or phrase that is made by arranging the letters of another word or phrase in a different order).
Convert the two numbers into strings and then follow the procedure to check if both are anagrams to each other or not.

Here is an efficient approach to check Anagrams. Steps involved in checking for ANAGRAMS:

1. If the length of both strings is unequal, then they can never be Anagrams.
2. Count the frequency of all the digits between `'0' to '9'` for both the strings for comparison.
3. Compare the frequency of all the digits from `'0' to '9'` of both strings as for being Anagrams to each other, the frequency of each character for both the strings should be equal.
4. If the frequency of any character is found to be unequal, break the loop as it can't be an Anagram.

```java
    public static boolean isANAGRAM(long n1, long n2)
    {
        String s1 = String.valueOf(n1);
        String s2 = String.valueOf(n2);
        if (s1.length() != s2.length())
            return false;
        
        int freq[] = new int[10];
        char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)   ++freq[ c1[i]-'0' ];
        for (int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++)   --freq[ c2[i]-'0' ];
        
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        if ( freq[i] != 0 )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm:

```
** check every occurrence of digit from first number is higher or not from every occurrence of digit from second number.

** if it does, then it is possible to construct/build second number from first number

** else, it is not possible.
```